# Dependency Injection with RepositoryProvider with BLoC

Tags: flutter, dart, bloc

Given I have a `Repository`:

```
class Repository {
 final DataSource dataSource;
 Repsoitory(this.dataSource);
}
```

and a `DataSource`:

```
class DataSource {
  final Dio dio;
  DataSource(this.dio);
}
```

and I would like to initialize `Dio` with these `BaseOptions`:

```
final baseOptions = BaseOptions(
  baseUrl: "https://myapi.com",
);
```

How would I do this using `RepositoryProvider`?

What I often saw was using something like this:

```
class App extends StatelessWidget {
  final Repository repository;
  App(this.repository);

  build(BuildContext context){
    return RepositoryProvider.value(
      value: repository,
    );
  }
}
```

and in `main`:

```
main(){
 final baseOptions = BaseOptions(...);
 final dio = Dio(baseOptions);
 final repository = Repository(dio);

 runApp(App(repository));
}
```

But this does not allow for `baseOptions` or `dio` to be easily mocked.

Any ideas?

Comment: Did you come up with any decent solution?

Comment: @pkuszewski No, I'm using Riverpod instead.